# .htaccess redirect subdomain 404 to main domain 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, http-status-code-404

I'm working with a site that used to use a subdomain to link to an externally hosted blog. This has since been deleted and incorporated into the main site. The subdomain now just houses a .htaccess file with 301 redirects for the blog articles.

I also have a 404 page set up for any other remaining links to the subdomain. The problem is that I want the 404 to be served from the main domain, not the subdomain. Instead of blog.example.com/404, I want to serve www.example.com/404.

Not sure if it matters, but on the server, my subdomain is a folder inside of the main domain:
html/ = www.example.com
html/blog/ = blog.example.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove any 404 ErrorDocument line from `DOCUMENT_ROOT/blog/.htaccess`
2. In your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` add this line:

   ErrorDocument 404 /blog/404.html